# Getting unterminated string literal error on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, string

while using this code code am getting an error like `unterminated string literal` on server but working nicely on localhost,here is my code

```
var bill_no = '<?php echo $bill_no; ?>';
          if(msg ==bill_no)
          {
            console.log(msg);
            window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control";
            toastr.success('Token No is ' + msg, 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000})
          }
```

My controller looks like this

```
if($data)
{

   echo $bill_no;

}
else
{
   echo "NO";

}
```

how to solve this.. `$bill_no` contains value like this `000235`

Comment: Perhaps $bill_no contains a quote on server.

Comment: @Adder how can we remove that

Comment: or may be a new line ?

Comment: @angel.bonev i already tried that,getting error like `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: @user_777 [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)

Comment: Can't add quote in the comment :/

Comment: `var bill_no = "<?php echo addslashes($bill_no); ?>";` This  escapes the double quotes that may be in bill_no for javascript.

Comment: @Adder still having the same error

Comment: In which line is the error? Is it even in code that you showed us or elsewhere?

Comment: the error is at here `var bill_no = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bill_no, ENT_QUOTES); ?>";`

Comment: Try `var bill_no = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$bill_no)), ENT_QUOTES); ?>";`

Comment: @angel.bonev still its looks same

Comment: I made a mistake with the htmlspecialchars, that one is to escape html attributes. To escape javascript, use addslashes.

Comment: @Adder i had done with that already like this  `<?php echo addslashes($bill_no); ?>` but still have error

Comment: what will be the solution for this

Comment: I think the error might be somewhere else, try hardcoding the bill no. to check this: `var bill_no = '000235';`

Comment: i had added the controller function there

Comment: Are you sure the error is not on the admin_control page? Because you redirect to there. Btw. the toastr.success function should never be called because you redirect the page to the new location before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>app/admin_control"
```

I think the problem could be here. When you are trying to concat the url using php variable. The resulting URL gets caught in htmlspecialcharaters. try hard coding a url and check.